# Can Automator be used to visit/upload/save images from a website?

Tags: applescript, automator, automation

I have a folder on desktop with png images.
I'd like the images to be sent to a website (Vectoriser.ai).
Uploaded one image at a time (multi drop is not available) and save the result to another folder on desktop.

The website process is four steps,
upload/press ok/press download/press another download button.

I couldn't find anything in the search results that match my requirements exactly, so I'm wondering can this even be done?

I'm using an old iMac 2011 High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: What have you tried to do, but it failed to work?

Comment: Ive been using Automator for less than a week. Ive just about figured out how to make my first working rename app from bits ive read in other threads. I think im just struggling to ask the search bar the right questions, due to lack of proper terminology understanding. I was just wondering if it's actually possible.

Answer (score 0):

There certainly isn't an Automator action for dragging a file onto a webpage that will process it on the server side; though it may be possible to replicate that action with some amount of scripting.

I'd suggest looking at Mac software that will vectorize bitmaps, which you can run locally, and then automate files into it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know Ben. I've been playing with watch me do and all failures/errors are google chrome related. I tried inkspace and gimp and both fall short in quality. I'll need to take a break for a few days I think and try again with a fresh head.
 Information overload